# rigidity of representations of dehn fillings on the figure eight knot

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

Consider a Dehn filling of the figure eight knot with coprime parameters (p,q) denoted by M.
I am interested in the representation space of M in $SU_2$.

I wonder wether all such representations are infinitesimally isolated or said differently 
$H^1(M,Ad_\rho)=0$ for all non central $\rho:\pi_1(M)\to SU_2$.

The representation space of the figure eight knot is described (except for the 2 isolated solutions) by the curve 
$$F(x,y)=cos(x)+1-cos(4y)+cos(2y)=0$$ 
where $x$ and $y$ are the angles of the meridian and the longitude respectively.

The question is equivalent to saying that the line of equation $px+qy=0$ meets transversely the curve $F(x,y)=0$. 
This is clear for geometric reasons if $|p/q|<\sqrt{20}$ and can be proven for $|p/q|>\sqrt{20}$ by showing that the polynomial 
$$\Phi=X^{2p}-X^{p+4q}+X^{p+2q}+2X^p+X^{p-2q}-X^{p-4q}+1$$
has simple roots except $-1$ if $p$ is odd and $\pm i$ if $4|p$.

This is a simple test which I ran with my computer for all $p<200$: the answer is yes. But I don't find a general argument. Any help is welcome!

Julien Marché

ps: of course a theoretical argument would be better but I don't know any.

Comment: Do you know the reps themselves are isolated up to conjugation?

Comment: Julien -- what exactly is $Ad_\rho$? Is it $\rho$ composed with the adjoint repesentation?

Comment: @algori: yes. Then $H^1(\pi; ad_\rho)$ is identified (by Weil) with the zariski tangent space of the space of conjugacy classes of representations at $\rho$. So Julien is wondering if all non-central reps are "smooth" 0-diml varieties. Since the Figure 8 alexander polynomial has no roots on the unit circle, the usual way to find non-smooth isolated non-central reps of surgeries doesn't apply. (e.g. the corresponding answer is no for the trefoil)

Comment: thanks for your comments. I confirm the answer of Paul, Ad$_\rho$ is $\rho$ composed with the Adjoint representation. 
I think we know that the reps are isolated by conjugation because if not, it would mean that the curve F=0 would contain segments of the line $px+qy=0$ which is certainly no true, but I still cannot show that there are no tangency.

Comment: @Julien: I know, it is old question, but I do find it interesting. However, there is something odd with what you wrote: It seems that you know how to prove your conjecture for all values of p, q except in the case $|p/q|^2=20$. However, the equality cannot happen since $p, q$ are integers. Maybe 20 should be replaced with something else? On general grounds, it follows from the work of Kerchkoff and Hodgson that representation of fundamental group of a Dehn filling of a hyperbolic manifold which belongs to the "main component" is infinitesimally rigid, except for a controlled...

Comment: and finite number of special case. If more is known about the group, then the exceptional cases can be analyzed with the aid of a computer. This leaves other components of the character variety. If you are lucky, then all $Sl(2, C)$ representations are either reducible or belong to the main component. Also, it is an open problem if character varieties of homology 3-spheres can be nonreduced at Zariski dense representations. (For non-homology spheres, nonreducibility can happen.)

Comment: Thank you very much Misha for your comment that I just discovered. Indeed I meant that for |p/q|^2>20 only a computer can do it for a given pair (p,q). I checked it for p<200 and it works. 
For the second part of your comment, you mention the results of Hodgson and Kerchkoff but I would like to be sure of something. As far as I understand, the rigidity holds only for the hyperbolic representation of the Dehn filling, it does not give information on the (many) others representations. Am I right?

